# Python 3.6 equivalent of md5 digest() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

I'am having trouble in achieving the same results of md5 digest() method from Python 2.7 in Python 3.6.

Python 2.7:

```
import md5

encryption_base  = 'cS35jJYp15kjQf01FVqA7ubRaNOXKPmYGRbLUiimX0g3frQhzOZBmTSni4IEjHLWYMMioGaliIz5z8u2:abcdefghkmnopqrstuvwxyz:4'
digest = md5.new (encryption_base).digest()
print(digest)

#T┼Çƒ×ÞRK(M<¶┤#  ²
```

Python 3.6:

```
from hashlib import md5

encryption_base  = 'cS35jJYp15kjQf01FVqA7ubRaNOXKPmYGRbLUiimX0g3frQhzOZBmTSni4IEjHLWYMMioGaliIz5z8u2:abcdefghkmnopqrstuvwxyz:4'
digest = md5(encryption_base.encode()).digest()
print(digest)

#b'T\xc5\x80\x9f\x9e\xe8RK(M<\xf4\xb4#\t\xfd'
```

How can I get the same string as in the Python 2.7 result? .hexdigest is not the case for this also.

Comment: Hexdigest gives exactly the same output on Python 2 and 3, why do you think it is not? For both scripts that'd be `54c5809f9ee8524b284d3cf4b42309fd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the exact same result, a bytestring. The only difference is that in Python 3 printing a bytestring gives you a *debugging-friendly representation*, not the raw bytes. That's because the raw bytes are not necessarily printable and `print()` needs *Unicode strings*.

If you must have the same output, write the bytes directly to the `stdout` buffer, bypassing the Unicode `TextIOWrapper()` that takes care of encoding text to the underlying locale codec:

```
import sys

digest = md5(encryption_base.encode('ASCII')).digest()
sys.stdout.buffer.write(digest + b'\n')
```

Note that you must ensure that you define your `encryption_base` value as a `bytes` value too, *or* at least encode it to the same codec, ASCII, like I did above.

Definining it as a bytestring gives you the same value as in Python 2 without encoding:

```
encryption_base  = b'cS35jJYp15kjQf01FVqA7ubRaNOXKPmYGRbLUiimX0g3frQhzOZBmTSni4IEjHLWYMMioGaliIz5z8u2:abcdefghkmnopqrstuvwxyz:4'
```

When you use `str.encode()` without explicitly setting an argument, you are encoding to UTF-8. IF your `encryption_base` string only consists of ASCII codepoints, the result would be the same, but not if you have any Latin-1 or higher codepoints in there too. Don't conflate bytes with Unicode codepoints! See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html to fully understand the difference and how that difference applies to Python 2 and 3.

Comment: happens that I need to call ord() in each character of the resulting string. In python 2.7 the ord call works perfectly, but in 3.6 I get error: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: Why do you need to call `ord()`? If you just want the integer values, then in Python 3 *you already have integers*, as `bytes` objects are really iterables of integers.

Comment: So `digest[0]` in Python 3 is the integer 84, while in Python 2 you have to use `ord()` to get the same integer.

Comment: Oh god, I didnt notice that. Huge thanks for the enlightment Martijin. Also, great link you provided there.